# How to get colors for events in SP2013 Calendar?

Tags: 2013, calendar

I have question how can I setup Calendar with colors on every event.

1. I've created separated Views for every Category of the meeting.
2. I've overlayed multiple calendars.
3. Result what I've got is that: legend is coloured, events are not. Screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: did you try this http://summit7systems.com/color-code-calendar-events-in-sharepoint/

Comment: To me, it looks like you are using custom css for your calendar. I'm sure you have done it right, but i think that your custom css overrides the overlays. Use F12 developer tools to check the css.

Answer (score 0):

The important step here is to use calendar overlays for all the different calendar views you created and color code them. The link Waqar has provided has step by step process to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Shame to admit, but this issue was resolved by enabling Compatibility View in MSIE 11.0.